# Sieve of Eratosthenes JavaScript implementation - performance very slow over a certain number

Tags: javascript, performance, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I've been playing around with the code challenges on projecteuler.net. A few of them involve prime numbers, so I've created a function to find them based on the sieve of Eratosthenes.

It works fine, and is reasonably quick for small numbers, but much slower for the challenges that involve the larger numbers, like 2million. So to try to improve my function I tested it to see how the performance changes and discovered that the time it takes to run shoots up dramatically at a specific number, not gradually as you might expect.

I'm running this on the chrome dev tools. It consistently takes about 1.5 seconds for 354,957 and 15 seconds for 354,958. I found this very odd and was wondering if anyone had experienced similar or new why this might be?

Below is my code. I know it's not perfect and there a much (much) quicker implementations out there.

```html
function getPrimesUnder(number) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();

  var numbers = [2];
  var sqNum = Math.sqrt(number);
  var i, x;
  for (i = 3; i < number; i = i + 2) {
    numbers.push(i);
  }
  for (x = 0; numbers[x] < sqNum; x++) {
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length ; i++){
       if (numbers[i] > numbers[x]) {
        if(numbers[i] % numbers[x] === 0){
          numbers.splice(i, 1)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  var end = new Date().getTime();
  var time = end - start;
  alert('Execution time: ' + time/1000 + ' seconds');
  return numbers;

}
```

Comment: That's not a Sieve of Erathosthenes implementation.

Comment: Here's a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/sieve-test2) to compare.

Comment: Calling splice deep inside nested loops... ouch

Comment: @Pointy why isn't it? It's slightly modified, e.g. I don't bother pushing even numbers into the Array, but the essence of it is the same.

Comment: See [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, however I'm not asking how this can be improved. I know it's not perfect, but I'm using this as a way to teach myself. My main question was why it should take so much longer when increasing the input number by only 1. Has anyone encountered this before? Do you have similar results if you run the code?

Comment: That doesn't explain how it's not a sieve of Erathosthenes.

Comment: If that's your main question  you should ask a completely new question "Why is splicing an array so much slower for bigger arrays? in the V8 tag. And remove all redundancy about primes, it should just be about splice.

Comment: Your code pushes all odd numbers onto the list of primes. Not all odd numbers are prime numbers.

Comment: Have you checked to see whether the value that your function returns is actually a list of prime numbers?

Comment: Yes, it returns exactly the same as your code for below 100.

Comment: OK, then the simple answer to your question is that your code is doing far more work than it should in order to implement the algorithm properly.

Comment: It pushes all odd numbers into an array, not a list of primes. The function then goes through the array and removes multiples of each prime. Then finally returns the modified list, which is a list of primes.

Comment: Right, and that's not what Mr. Erathosthenes proposed.

Comment: @JamieC "Thanks for the answers, however I'm not asking how this can be improved." - Welcome to CodeReview! All code here is fair game for reviewers, and all topics too. I hope you have a good time here, and get some useful feedback!

Answer (score 6):

In a real Sieve implementation, your "sieve" is the array that keeps track of the multiples of primes. You'll also want to remember the values of the primes, since the array is basically an array of Boolean values.

Thus, the first thing you do is create the array. It has to be as big as the biggest target value:

```
function primesBelow(n) {
  var sieve = new Array(n);
```

Upon initialization, that array is empty, and thankfully in JavaScript empty array elements look `false`.  So we start with 2:

```
  var primes = [];
  for (var test = 2; test < n; ++test) {
    if (sieve[test]) {
      // NOT PRIME
    }
    else {
```

If the sieve value is **unset** at a particular test number, that means that that value is the multiple of no known prime. Hence, we can tick off that sieve entry (even though we'll never see it again) and all multiples of that newly-found prime:

```
      primes.push(test);
      for (var pm = test; pm < n; pm += test)
        sieve[pm] = true;
    }
  }
```

(Note that we really could start the value of `pm` at `test * test`, because the first composite number bigger than `test` for which `test` will be the only prime factor will be its square.)

When we start the loop at 2, the first prime we find is, clearly, 2 itself, since the sieve is freshly created and completely empty. So all the multiples of 2 will be set to `true` on the first pass. The second value to test is 3, and `sieve[3]` will still be `false`, because 3 is not a multiple of 2 and is therefore also prime.

The first composite number encountered will be 4, because its slot in the sieve will have been set to `true` when we found 2. Then 5 will be tested, and its sieve slot will also be empty, so it's prime too.

Note that the first odd composite number to be found is 9, which is not prime because its sieve slot will have been set to `true` when the loop found 3.

The complete code:

```
function primesBelow(n) {
  var sieve = new Array(n);
  var primes = [];
  for (var test = 2; test < n; ++test) {
    if (sieve[test]) {
      // NOT PRIME
    }
    else {
      primes.push(test);
      for (var pm = test; pm < n; pm += test)
        sieve[pm] = true;
    }
  }
  return primes;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

numbers.splice is the culprit, this will take O(n) time each time it is called. And it is called O(n) times.

do a proper sieve instead:

```
for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    numbers.push(i);
}

 for (x = 2; numbers[x] < sqNum; x++) {
    if(numbers[x]==0)
        continue;

    for (i = x*2; i < numbers.length ; i+=x){
          numbers[i]=0;
      }
    }
  }
```

Otherwise use `filter` to remove all the multiples

```
  for (x = 0; numbers[x] < sqNum; x++) {
    if(numbers[x]==0)
        continue;

    numbers = numbers.filter(function(a){return a % numbers[x] != 0});
  }
```

Comment: This isn't a Sieve of Erathosthenes either.

Comment: @Pointy how so? except that I use an int array where numbers[i]==i if prime instead of a boolean

Comment: You don't want to keep track of the multiples of *every* number, just the primes.

Comment: @Pointy there that's better ain't it

Comment: I'm not sure why you initialize the sieve that way; none of the entries (other than `numbers[0]`) will ever be 0 in the actual loop.